# Getting a php script to run at a certain time each day independently each day?

Tags: php

I am in need of something like this I need a script to run independently each day at a certain time without fail, the script will be for PDO mysql and some other things,

Can anyone point me in the right direction??

Thanks

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=cronjob

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102949/how-to-poll-email-with-hosted-solutions-php-or-asp

Comment: I am designing a website in localhost, but anything I need to host the actual website I will have, and I am running on windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a script on a specific date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381032/run-a-script-on-a-specific-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PHP is configured to run from the commandline you can simply setup either a cronjob (`crontab -e`) (Linux) or a scheduled task (Windows) where you run the php file(s) you want to run.

```
php -f /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: Thank you task scheduler will have to do for now :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux, use a [CRON Job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). For Windows, use a [Scheduled Task](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).

There are also services that do this online. A quick Google search returns [this site](http://www.setcronjob.com/).